# memset and struct with getters/setters

Tags: c++

I have a simple pod struct, for example:

```
struct T
{
    int x;
    float z;
}
```

I want to make a data private and add getters/setters. Can I use memset on that struct ?

```
memset(obj, 0, sizeof(T));
```

Comment: Very bad style! Writing bytes across a data structure looks wrong to me! That is far away from object oriented programming.

Comment: memcpy vs memset?

Comment: @Klaus yes I confused them and removed comment and answer. Though they are closely related and I still dont see how it is bad style. OP is not giving any context and I dont find it hard to imagine a context where `memset` is completely fine to be used. I'd be curious to hear a good argument (I mean more than that it looks wrong to you), but I don't want to spam this Q&A ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818: Is it defined how an implementation stores a float value? Is it guaranteed that a float filled up with 8 bit ints 0 are resulting in a zero float value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make a data private and add getters/setters. Can I use memset on that struct ?

Yes, you can use memset as long as the class is trivially copyable, and the object isn't a potentially overlapping subobject.

P.S. Memsetting float with zero bytes isn't technically guaranteed by C++ to set it to value zero, although it probably does so on most systems. Any other value for the bytes would be even less meaningful.

P.P.S Pointers have the same problem: Null is not guaranteed to be all bits zero.

P.P.P.S. I cannot think of a good reason to use memset 0 instead of using value initialisation and assignment if your intention is to set the values zero.

Comment: Are you shure that c++ guarantees that all bits 0 in float memory are a float value of 0? Is this guaranteed by the c++ standard?

Comment: @Klaus But where is the requirement in the question to get `0.0f` after memsetting all bytes to zero? What could be [dangerous](https://web.archive.org/web/20100125081223/http://www.dmh2000.com/cpp/dswap.shtml) is getting some kind of FP exception when an invalid bit pattern is written into `float`.

Comment: @Klaus C++ doesn't guarantee anything about float representation. IEEE-754 standard, which is supported fairly ubiquitously does guarantee that.

Comment: @Evg I suppose that my suggestion to use value initialisation would have a different meaning than memset in such exoitc case.

Comment: @Evg: OK, you say it is save to overwrite a struct with zeros, but the value of the strcutures float content is non portable and dependent on the implementation. OK, but is that what a user expects :-)

Comment: @Klaus, I agree with your claim that it is a non-portable and bad idea (if the intent is to zero both data members).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* fill your struct with 0, but the result is may be not what you expect!

- it is not guaranteed by the C++ standard that a float which has in memory all bits zero is the representation of 0.0f! It can be anything and is depending on the implementation! If you use it, your code is not portable and the behaviour can change with next compiler release. OK, typically it will be 0.0f, but using "undefined initialisation" is very bad style!
- the compiler is typically not able to optimize the code where memory is written by raw memset. If you use value initialization with a constant, the compiler can optimize the following code, because it knows the value of the data. But with memset this is maybe not the case.
- you are filling also the gaps between your data, what is maybe also not what you need or expect.
- in general memset in OOP is mysterious and typically not faster as default construction.

My advice: If your data types have *not* a clearly defined representation given by the c++ standard, you should *not* use `memset` on them.

Comment: the last sentence has too many negations, no? "never for types which are not defined as float and double" -> ergo it would be fine to use it for types that are float or double...

Comment: @idclev463035818: Better now :-) I think it was correct before but if it disturbs the readers eyes I will give it a better try :-)

Comment: not a native speaker here, but now it is much more clear.